# request and response within the "asd1" session. I use ('/session="asd1"/') - the result is 1 line, but I need to get the output of all lines of 1 log

Tags: awk

```
[24/11/11 09:49:57:538 EST]  DEBUG
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Request session="asd1" id=23243>
<type>Balance</type>
</Request>
[24/11/11 10:50:57:538 EST]  DEBUG
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Request session="assa" id=dr5453>
<type>Balance</type>
</Request>
[24/11/11 11:51:57:676 EST]  DEBUG
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Request session="sadsd" id=frre54>
<type>Balance</type>
</Request>
[24/11/11 17:49:57:538 EST]  DEBUG
<?xml version="1.1" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Response session="asd1" id=545645>
<type>Withdrawal</type>
<code>0000</code>
</Response>
```

request and response within the "asd1" session. I use the keyword search command ('/session="asd1"/') and it gives only one line in which a match occurs, but I need to get the output of all lines of 1 log. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Meta: I'm surprised this isn't a duplicate, but on several tries I didn't find any.

*If you use GNU awk (sometimes identified as gawk to distinguish it from other awk(s) that may be present)* you can use a regexp for RS (Record Separator) and get the match in RT

```
gawk -vRS='</Request>|</Response>' '/session="asd1"/{printf "%s",$0 RT}' <data
```

For other awks, if there is a (single) character not used in your data you can 'patch' the data to use that as a record delimiter; HTML shouldn't use any control characters other than CRLF and (maybe) HT, so a 'weird' character like ETX (\003, control-C) or GS (\035, control-]) should be safe:

```
awk '{printf "%s", $0 ($0~"</Request>|</Response>"?"\035":"\n")}' <data \
| awk -vRS="\035" '/session="asd1"/' # default trims \035 and adds back newline
```

Alternatively you can explicitly accumulate a multi-line block and then process it:

```
awk '{x=x RS $0} $0~"</Request>|</Response>"{if(x~/session="asd1"/) print substr(x,2); x=""}' <data
```